# Show that $\left(X_{(1)} + X_{(n)}\right)/2$ is a consistent estimator for $\theta$

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be a random sample from the uniform distribution on the interval
$(\theta − 1/2, \theta + 1/2)$, where $\theta$ is unknown. Let $X_{(1)} = \min(X_1, \ldots , X_n)$ $X_{(n)} = \max(X_1, \ldots , X_n).$

Show that $\left(X_{(1)} + X_{(n)}\right)/2$ is a consistent estimator for $\theta$.

Not really sure where to start with this. I tried finding the MLE and saying that is was a consistent estimator but found that the fisher information is 0. I also tried using the MME but that got me no where.

Comment: Somewhat similar to recent question `2020216`. _Not_ a duplicate.

Comment: If you know the variances of $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)}$ I expect you can apply Chebyshev's inequality in the same way in which that is done in the proof of the weak law of large numbers. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I was told under certain conditions, MLE's are consitent estimators

Comment: @MichaelHardy I can find the variances but how would that help me?

Comment: The first comment is right. That you try to find the MLE shows conceptual issues on your side. You are given an estimator, you must show that _that_ estimator (not the MLE estimator) is consistent. Do you know what it means that an estimator is consistent? What is your definition?

Comment: @leonbloy it just seems unrealistic to find the variance of the given estimator. I though there might be a short cut

Comment: @AlexChavez I have no idea whay you mean. And you have not answered my question. BTW, Michael Hardy's answer is totally correct, and just hope it was not you who downvoted it.

Comment: @leonbloy : But if the estimator he was given were to turn out to be the MLE, then he could use a result on consistency of MLEs. $\qquad$

Comment: @AlexChavez : I've added a postscript on finding the variance. $\qquad$

Comment: @leonbloy before you come on here basically calling me dumb, check your facts first. Under certain conditions, MLE's are also consitent estimators, therefore if you could show $T_n$ is the MLE, you could conclude that it is consistent. However these certain conditions are not satisfied.

Comment: @AlexChavez I never called you dumb (nor even "basically") - I would call you (now) immature (especially if you voted down my other answer -didn't you?). Grow your skin. Computing the variance of an estimator is the common way of proving consistency (because variance going  zero $\implies$ estimator converges in squared mean $\implies$ estimator converges in probability - which is the _definition_ of consistency). Most practical consistent estimators have also vanishing variance (though this is sufficient but not necessary), and it's the first thing that one normally tries to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the variance $\sigma_n^2$ of this estimator $\widehat\theta_n$. (The variances of the maximum and minimum separately are not enough, since they are not independent.) If you can show that $\sigma_n^2\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, then by Chebyshev's inequality you can say for every $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\Pr( |\widehat\theta_n - \theta| > \varepsilon) = \Pr\left( \left| \frac{\widehat\theta_n - \theta}{\sigma_n} \right| > \frac\varepsilon{\sigma_n} \right) \le \frac{\sigma_n^2}{\varepsilon^2} \to 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty.
$$
And there you have convergence in probability of $\widehat\theta_n$ to $\theta$.

**Postscript:**

\begin{align}
F_{X_{(1)},X{(n)}}(u,v) & = \Pr( X_{(1)} \le u\ \&\ X_{(n)} \le v) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(X_{(n)} \le v)  - \Pr(u>X_{(1)}\ \&\ X_{(n)} \le v) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(\text{All of } X_1,\ldots,X_n \text{ are} \le v) - \Pr(\text{All are between } u \text{ and } v.) \\[10pt]
& = (v-(\theta - \tfrac 1 2))^n - (v-u)^n).
\end{align}
From this you can find the density
$$
f_{X_{(1)},X{(n)}}(u,v) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial u\,\partial v} F_{X_{(1)},X{(n)}}(u,v)
$$
and then you can use that to find $\sigma_n^2$.

Note that if $\theta - \dfrac 1 2 =0$ then the variance is the same as if $\theta-\dfrac 1 2$ is anything else, so for simplicity you may as well put $0$ there.

**PPS:**
$$
\operatorname{var}(X_{(n)} + X_{(1)}) = \operatorname{E}\Big((X_{(n)} + X_{(1)})^2 \Big) - \Big( \operatorname{E}(X_{(n)} + X_{(1)}) \Big)^2 = \operatorname{E}\Big((X_{(n)} + X_{(1)})^2 \Big) - \theta^2.
$$
$$
\operatorname{E}\Big((X_{(n)} + X_{(1)})^2 \Big) = \iint\limits_{\left[ \theta - \frac 1 2,\, \theta + \frac 1 2 \right]^2} (u+v)^2 f_{X_{(1)},\,X_{(n)}} (u,v)\, d(u,v).
$$

Comment: I understand how to find the distribution of ($X_{(1)}$, $X_{(1)}$), and I understand how to find$E((X_{(1)} +X_{(1)})/2)$, however finding the 2nd moment (in order to calculate the variance) is what is giving me problems

Comment: @AlexChavez : I've extended my answer somewhat further now, but it still doesn't go all the way to the bottom line. Before doing that, I might consider that it may not be necessary to find the variance: Just finding an upper bound on the variance is enough if the upper bound goes to $0$ as $n$ grows. $\qquad$

Comment: In PPS part, should there be $/2$ everywhere? I mean $\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{\color{red}{2}}$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative of computing the variance (more direct, but still not very easy), we can do this by definition. (Not the common way, but it can be instructive).

We need to show that the estimator converges in probability to the true value. For the sake of notation simplicity, let's take $\theta =0$ (you should replace for $\theta$ for the general case).

Then we need to show that for any fixed $\epsilon>0$, $$\lim _{n \to \infty}P(|\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}|>\epsilon)\to 0 \tag{1}$$

Intutively, we guess that, as $n$ grows, $ X_{(1)}$  will concentrate near $-\frac12$ and $ X{(n)}$ near $\frac12$

Formally: let $A_{\delta,n}$ ($B_{\delta,n}$) be the event that the distance from $ X_{(1)}$ to $-\frac12$ (resp from $ X_{(n)}$ to $\frac12$) is greater than $ \delta$ . Then, for  $1 > \delta>0$ , $$P(A_{\delta,n})=P(B_{\delta,n})=(1-\delta)^n \to 0 \tag{2}$$

To show that this implies $(1)$:

$$\left|\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{X_{(1)}+\frac12+X_{(n)}-\frac12}{2}\right|\le 
\frac12\left|X_{(1)}+\frac12\right|
+
\frac12 \left|X_{(n)}-\frac12\right| \tag{3}
$$

Then $$P(|\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}|>\epsilon)\le P(A_{\epsilon,n} \cap B_{\epsilon,n})\le (1-\epsilon)^n \to 0 \tag{4}$$

Comment: what if $\epsilon > 1$ ?

Comment: We always have $|\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}|\le 1$ Hence, if $\epsilon >1$ , the probability in $(1)$ (before the limit) is strictly zero.